# Using a ViewController with a dot in its name through storyboards

Tags: swift, interface-builder

Is it possible to reference a UIViewController with a dot in its name through a storyboard?

Login.ViewController for example?

```
class Login {
    class ViewController: UIViewController {}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "name"?  The storyboard identifier for the scene? The identifier for the segue?  The class name?  Yes, for the first two, no for the last

Comment: Classname - should have been more clear.

Comment: Is there anyway to create an alias for the dot operator in Swift then? Something like typealias for an operator like that?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  A class name can't contain a '.'

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Builder is not aware of nested classes that are available in Swift, so you cannot set a nested view controller class as the class for a view controller scene in a storyboard.

Apple may address this in the future or you could consider posting a feature request